# communication with remote inferior python shell slowing down code editing

Tags: python, tramp, ssh, subprocess, inferior-buffer

I am working with python code on a remote machine using tramp. Once I start the start the remote python shell, the editor window starts to freeze up for around/under a second second at a time, but very frequently. All I am doing is moving around in the code file. It happens with both python and ipython shells.

When this happens messages flash by in the mini-buffer indicating communication with the python shell. Some messages indicate that documentation is being retrieved, even though I am not requesting it. These messages are not recorded in any other buffer like `*Messages*`.

How can I reduce/stop this?

My .ssh/config already has:

```
Host *
 ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
 ControlMaster auto
 ControlPersist yes
 ServerAliveInterval 3
 ServerAliveCountMax 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is eldoc. Emacs ships with `global-eldoc-mode` set to `t` and `eldoc-idle-delay` set to 0.5 seconds. If you are moving around in a file you can generate an awful lot of eldoc calls, which can make emacs unusable over slow or multi-hop ssh connections.